# Regular expressions in findstr

Tags: windows, regex, command-line, findstr

I'm doing a little string validation with `findstr` and its `/r` flag to allow for regular expressions. In particular I'd like to validate integers.

The regex

```
^[0-9][0-9]*$
```

worked fine for non-negative numbers but since I now support negative numbers as well I tried

```
^([1-9][0-9]*|0|-[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

for either positive or negative integers or zero.

The regex works fine *theoretically*. I tested it in PowerShell and it matches what I want. However, with

```
findstr /r /c:"^([1-9][0-9]*|0|-[1-9][0-9]*)$"
```

it doesn't.

While I know that `findstr` doesn't have the most advanced regex support (even below Notepad++ which is probably quite an achievement), I would have expected such simple expressions to work.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Note to the editor: The *windows* tag is a little superfluous, given that `findstr` only exists there ...

Comment: Rössel: Tags are there to help find things. A moderate redundancy doesn't hurt in this case.

Comment: I'd never search for a tag as overcrowded as *windows* ;-) but if you think it'll help ...

Comment: and don't forget the tag usage to filter out questions. Those overcrowded tags as *windows*, *linux*, *apple*, are **very** convenient to *ignore*

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This works for me:

```
findstr /r "^[1-9][0-9]*$ ^-[1-9][0-9]*$ ^0$"
```

If you don't use the `/c` option, the `<Strings>` argument is treated as a space-separated *list* of search strings, which makes the space a sort of crude replacement for the `|` construct.  (As long as your regexes don't contain spaces, that is.)

Comment: Aah, right you are. That one I forgot. Yes, spaces in the RE would be bad, then but that won't be an issue here.

Comment: I'm reluctant to up-vote such an abuse of regular expression syntax, but you solved my problem, thank-you! :-p

Answer (score 9):

Argh, I should have read [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732459(WS.10).aspx) better. `findstr` apparently doesn't support alternations (`|`).

So I'm probably back to multiple invocations or replacing the whole thing with a custom parser eventually.

This is what I do for now:

```
set ERROR=1
rem Test for zero
echo %1|findstr /r /c:"^0$">nul 2>&1
if not errorlevel 1 set ERROR=
rem Test for positive numbers
echo %1|findstr /r /c:"^[1-9][0-9]*$">nul 2>&1
if not errorlevel 1 set ERROR=
rem Test for negative numbers
echo %1|findstr /r /c:"^-[1-9][0-9]*$">nul 2>&1
if not errorlevel 1 set ERROR=
```

Comment: As suggested by Alan Moore, if your search string does not contain spaces, then the space character will work like | in 'regular' regular expressions :) if all you're doing is looking to output any line that contains a list of strings you have.

Comment: @smartexpert: You may have noticed that Alan's answer is the accepted one.

Answer (score 3):

Or if you can,  download [grep for windows.](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm). Many more features than `findstr` provides.

Comment: No option here. This is a pure batch bignum library. I'll go for a proper parser when I'm done with the basic arithmetic. This will also be much better for proper error messages. For now multiple `findstr` invocations should suffice. Also, if it were just for features I'd just call PowerShell. Much easier, much more powerful.

Comment: I'm fascinated to I know went anyone would want bignums in a bat file.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler `regex` that achieves the same thing is possible, just add an optional minus to the start of your original expression:

```
^-?[0-9][0-9]*$
```

Comment: This is incorrect: it will match negative zero, and integers with a leading zero, either positive or negative: `-0`, `01`, `-042` etc. while OP's regex does not. Also, `findstr` does not support the `?` quantifier, so this answer really is not relevant to OP's issue

Answer (score -1):

Support for [regex in findstr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr) is quite limited. I suggest using **[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)**. The *find in files* option supports Perl Compatible Regular Expressions; results showing filename, line number and matching text can be easily copied to a text file.

Comment: Notepad++ is not really a useful option for non-interactive scripting.