# Extract a pattern from string using regular exp in batch script

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file

I want to extract a sub-string based on pattern from a given string in **batch script**.

Example:

```
Input :  ABCDEF-x32-32.12.20-298-date-20-12-17.exe
Required Output : 32.12.20-298  (i.e. <number>.<number>.<number>-<number>)
Regex (may be)  : [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+
```

How do I implement this in batch script??? I tried to implement the same using 'For' and 'findstr', but failed to do so.

Comment: will the substring you're looking for always be surrounded with hyphens `-` ?

Comment: It may or may not.

Comment: [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) searches for the sub-string, but it returns every *line* that contains a match; furthermore, `findstr` does not support the meta-character`+`, so `[0-9]+` must be written as `[0-9][0-9]*`. So basically, the wanted string is enclosed within non-numeric characters?

Comment: @aschipfl you may assume that. But the enclosing non-numeric characters on both side of wanted string may not be same.

Comment: Also consider using `powershell` if you can, its [support of regex](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.11.powershell.aspx) is much more modern.

Comment: Sorry, PowerShell is not in the options.

Comment: @MayankAgrawal I'm the one who feel sorry for you then, good luck with `cmd`'s 80s syntax ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match IP address by using 'findstr'? Or any other method of batch in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994395/how-to-match-ip-address-by-using-findstr-or-any-other-method-of-batch-in-wind)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. Answer to that post simply tells about how to match the pattern whereas this post is about how to extract the pattern from the given input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows batch does not have a good regular expression tool. The FINDSTR command has very limited (non-standard, and bugged) regex support. And it only can return entire lines that contain a match.

There are native Windows scripting languages that do have good support. PowerShell certainly does, And so do JScript and VBScript (available via CSCRIPT).

If you really want a pure script based regex solution from within a batch file, then you can use [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). It is hybrid batch/JScript that conveniently brings the power of JScript regular expressions to the batch world.

Full documentation is available via `jrepl /?`, or `jrepl /??` for paged help. Another important help command is `jrepl /?options` to get a summary of all available options, and `jrepl /?help` to get a summary of all available help.

Normally JREPL is used to perform a find/replace operation. But the `/MATCH` option ignores the required replace string and simply outputs the matching text.

Normally JREPL reads from stdin or a file. But the `/S` option reads the input from a variable.

The output is typically stdout or a file. But the `/RTN` option saves the result to an environment variable (entire result must fit within ~8kb).

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "str=ABCDEF-x32-32.12.20-298-date-20-12-17.exe"

:: Extract the string and print to the screen
call jrepl "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+" "" /match /s str

:: Extract the string and store it in variable out.
call jrepl "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+" "" /match /s str /rtn out
```