# why does the multiple "find" doesn't work in SC query

Tags: servercontrol

I wrote a command line

```
sc query PlugPlay | FIND "SERVICE_NAME" | FIND "STATE"
```

to list only the service name and its status but it's not giving any output.
Please correct me how to list the service name and its STATE (running or stopped) only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613826/regular-expressions-in-findstr

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Windows' built-in `findstr` command. If you give it multiple words to find, separated by spaces, it will print lines that match any word (i.e. `findstr "a b"` is equivalent to `grep -E 'a|b'`).

```
sc query plugplay | findstr "SERVICE_NAME STATE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Running two pipes like that is not an "or" operation, it is an "and" operation. It will only output lines that include both SERVICE_NAME and STATE (which will be none, so no output is correct). If you run just the first find it gives

```
C:\>sc query PlugPlay | FIND "SERVICE_NAME"
SERVICE_NAME: PlugPlay

C:\>
```

and thus the STATE information is already removed.

The windows `find` command is too simple and limited to do what you want, but it can be achieved using the unix [grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) command. From [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) for instance:

```
$ sc query PlugPlay | grep -E 'SERVICE_NAME|STATE'
SERVICE_NAME: PlugPlay
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
$
```